# A new continued fraction for Apéry's constant, $\zeta(3)$?

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta, continued-fractions

As a background, Ramanujan also gave a continued fraction for $\zeta(3)$ as

$\zeta(3) = 1+\cfrac{1}{u_1+\cfrac{1^3}{1+\cfrac{1^3}{u_2+\cfrac{2^3}{1+\cfrac{2^3}{u_3 + \ddots}}}}}\tag{1}$

where the sequence of $u_n$, starting with $n = 1$, is given by the *linear* function

$u_n = 4(2n-1) = 4, 12, 20, 28, \dots$

This has rather slow convergence. Using an approach similar to Apéry's of finding a faster converging version, I found via *Mathematica* that,

$\zeta(3) = \cfrac{6}{v_1 + \cfrac{1^3}{1 + \cfrac{1^3}{v_2 + \cfrac{2^3}{1 + \cfrac{2^3}{v_3 +\ddots}}}}}\tag{2}$

where the $v_n$ are now given by the *cubic* function

$v_n = 4(2n-1)^3 = 4, 108, 500, 1372, \dots$

*Question*: Can anyone prove that (2), with $v_n$ defined by the cubic function, is indeed true?

*Postscript*: A short description of Apéry's accelerated continued fractions for $\zeta(2)$ and $\zeta(3)$ is given [here](http://tpiezas.wordpress.com/2012/05/04/continued-fractions-for-zeta2-and-zeta3/).

Comment: The following _Mathematica_ code computes `2*len` terms of cfrac. `Apery2[len_] := Module[{res, vfun = 4 (2 # - 1)^3 &}, res = vfun[len + 1]; Do[res = vfun[k] + Divide[k^3, 1 + Divide[k^3, res]], {k, len, 1, -1}]; Divide[6, res]]`. With this code I checked `Apery2[330000] == N[Zeta[3], 10^6]` gives `True`. Computation took about 6 minutes.

Comment: Thanks, Sasha! I used a rather crude Mathematica code of looking for $v_n = an^3+bn^2+cn+d$ with unknown $(a,b,c,d)$. With a limited number of terms, its difference from $\zeta(3)$ was $10^{-50}$, several magnitudes MUCH less than the next best candidate which was $10^{-7}$.  Hence I knew this polynomial had to be it. But a rigorous proof is still needed.

Comment: @Tito Piezas III: this is one great result that deserves to land in the history books

Comment: @Nicco: What would be nicer is if someone can find a similar cfrac for $\zeta(5)$. See, for example, [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109490/using-mathematica-to-find-an-alternative-continued-fraction-for-zeta5) I asked in the _Mathematica_ forum.

Comment: Can you provide any resource to learn about "approach similar to Apéry's of finding a faster converging version" to go from $u_n = 4(2n-1)$ to $v_n= 4(2n-1)^3$?

Comment: @D.R. It's been about 12 years since this post, and I don't recall all the details. I do remember taking a quick look at Apery's paper and reasoning that if was able to accelerate [Euler's continued fraction formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_continued_fraction#Euler's_continued_fraction_formula) by using a cubic polynomial for the $b_n$, then maybe it was also possible to do so for Ramanujan's formula. So it was an approach by analogy. I was lucky that the coefficients were small enough since I did the search using _Mathematica_, and not from first principles.

Comment: I'm also curious as to a source on the Ramanujan continued fraction.

Comment: @D.R. You can find it in “Chapter 12 of Ramanujan’s Second Notebook” by Bruce Berndt. Back in 2010, I discussed it a bit in this article here https://web.archive.org/web/20230326021917/https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/0017

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here's a nice little *Mathematica* routine for evaluating Tito's continued fraction with precision `prec`:

```
prec = 10^4;
y = N[4, prec];
c = y; d = 0; k = 1;
u = 1; v = y;
While[True,
 c = 1 + u/c; d = 1/(1 + u d);
 h = c*d; y *= h;
 v += 96 k^2 + 8;
 c = v + u/c; d = 1/(v + u d);
 h = c*d; y *= h;
 If[Abs[h - 1] <= 10^-prec, Break[]];
 u += 3 k (k + 1) + 1;
 k++];
6/y
```

where I used the Lentz-Thompson-Barnett method for the evaluation.

For `prec = 10^4`, the thing evaluates in 120 seconds (via `AbsoluteTiming[]`), giving a result that agrees with $\zeta(3)$ to 10,000 digits.

One can consider the even part of Tito's CF, which converges at twice the rate of the original:

$$\cfrac{6}{5-\cfrac{u_1}{v_1-\cfrac{u_2}{v_2-\cfrac{u_3}{v_3-\cdots}}}}$$

where

$$\begin{align*}
u_k&=k^6\\
v_k&=(17k^2+17k+5)(2k+1)
\end{align*}$$

Here's *Mathematica* code corresponding to this CF:

```
prec = 10^4;
y = N[5, prec];
c = y; d = 0; k = 1;
While[True,
 u = k^6;
 v = (2 k + 1) ((17 k + 17) k + 5);
 c = v - u/c; d = 1/(v - u d);
 h = c*d; y *= h;
 If[Abs[h - 1] <= 10^-prec, Break[]];
 k++];
6/y
```

For `prec = 10^4`, the thing evaluates in 70 seconds (via `AbsoluteTiming[]`). There may be further ways to accelerate the convergence of the CF, but I have yet to look into them.

---

### Added, quite a bit later:

As it turns out, the even part I derived is precisely [Apéry's CF for $\zeta(3)$](http://www.ift.uni.wroc.pl/~mwolf/Poorten_MI_195_0.pdf) (thanks Américo!). Conversely put, Tito's CF is an *extension* of Apéry's CF. Here's how to derive Apéry's CF from Tito's CF (while proving convergence along the way).

We start from an *[equivalence transformation](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=BzaFb5h0NSgC&pg=PA77)* of Tito's CF. A general equivalence transformation of a CF

$$b_0+\cfrac{a_1}{b_1+\cfrac{a_2}{b_2+\cfrac{a_3}{b_3+\cdots}}}$$

with some sequence $\mu_k, k>0$ looks like this:

$$b_0+\cfrac{\mu_1 a_1}{\mu_1 b_1+\cfrac{\mu_1 \mu_2 a_2}{\mu_2 b_2+\cfrac{\mu_2 \mu_3 a_3}{\mu_3 b_3+\cdots}}}$$

Now, given a CF

$$b_0+\cfrac{a_1}{b_1+\cfrac{a_2}{b_2+\cdots}}$$

one can transform this into a CF of the form

$$b_0+\cfrac{w_1}{1+\cfrac{w_2}{1+\cdots}}$$

where $w_1=\dfrac{a_1}{b_1}$ and $w_k=\dfrac{a_k}{b_k b_{k-1}}$ for $k > 1$, where we used $\mu_k=\dfrac1{b_k}$. Applying this transformation to Tito's CF yields the CF

$$\cfrac{\frac32}{1+\cfrac{w_2}{1+\cfrac{w_3}{1+\cdots}}}$$

where $w_{2k}=\dfrac{k^3}{4(2k-1)^3}$ and $w_{2k+1}=\dfrac{k^3}{4(2k+1)^3}$. (You can easily demonstrate that this transformed CF and Tito's CF have identical convergents.)

At this point, we find that since the $w_k \leq\dfrac14$, we have convergence of the CF by [Worpitzky's theorem](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=BzaFb5h0NSgC&pg=PA135).

Now, we move on to extracting the [even part](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=BzaFb5h0NSgC&pg=PA86) of this transformed CF. Recall that if a CF has the sequence of convergents

$$u_0=b_0,u_1=b_0+\cfrac{a_1}{b_1},u_2=b_0+\cfrac{a_1}{b_1+\cfrac{a_2}{b_2}},\dots$$

then the even part is the CF whose convergents are $u_0,u_2,u_4,\dots$ (Analogously, there is the *odd part* with the sequence of convergents $u_1,u_3,u_5,\dots$)

Now, given a CF of the form

$$b_0+\cfrac{w_1}{1+\cfrac{w_2}{1+\cdots}}$$

its even part is the CF

$$b_0+\cfrac{w_1}{1+w_2-\cfrac{w_2 w_3}{1+w_3+w_4-\cfrac{w_4 w_5}{1+w_5+w_6-\cdots}}}$$

Thus, the even part of the previously transformed CF is given by

$$\cfrac{\frac32}{\frac54-\cfrac{\beta_1}{\delta_1-\cfrac{\beta_2}{\delta_2-\cdots}}}$$

where

$$\begin{align*}
\beta_k&=\frac{k^3}{4(2k-1)^3}\frac{k^3}{4(2k+1)^3}=\frac{k^6}{16(2k-1)^3(2k+1)^3}\\
\delta_k&=1+\frac{k^3}{4(2k+1)^3}+\frac{(k+1)^3}{4(2k+1)^3}=\frac{17k^2+17k+5}{4(2k+1)^2}
\end{align*}$$

We're almost there! We only need to perform another equivalence transformation, which I'll split into two steps to ease understanding. First, the easy one with $\mu_k=4$, which yields the CF

$$\cfrac{6}{5-\cfrac{16\beta_1}{4\delta_1-\cfrac{16\beta_2}{4\delta_2-\cdots}}}$$

The last step is to cancel out the odd integer denominators of the $\beta_k$ and $\delta_k$; to do this, we take $\mu_k=(2k+1)^3$; this finally yields the CF

$$\cfrac{6}{5-\cfrac{u_1}{v_1-\cfrac{u_2}{v_2-\cfrac{u_3}{v_3-\cdots}}}}$$

where

$$\begin{align*}
u_k&=k^6\\
v_k&=(17k^2+17k+5)(2k+1)
\end{align*}$$

and this is Apéry's CF.

---

For completeness, I present a formula for the odd part of Tito's CF, after some post-processing with a few equivalence transformations:

$$\zeta(3)=\frac32-\cfrac{81}{\lambda_1-\cfrac{\eta_1}{\lambda_2-\cfrac{\eta_2}{\lambda_3-\ddots}}}$$

where

$$\begin{align*}
\eta_k&=4\times(4k^4+8k^3+k^2-3k)^3=4\times10^3,\,4\times126^3,\dots\\
\lambda_k&=8\times(68k^6-45k^4+12k^2-1)=8\times34,\,8\times3679,\dots
\end{align*}$$

The formula is somewhat more complicated, and converges at the same rate as the even part.

Comment: Since $v_{k}=\left( 17k^{2}+17k+5\right) (2k+1)=34k^{3}+51k^{2}+27k+5$, this even part is exactly Apéry's continued fraction expansion for $\zeta (3)$

$$\begin{equation*}
\zeta (3)=\dfrac{6}{5+\overset{\infty }{\underset{n=1}{\mathbb{K}}}\dfrac{-n^{6}}{34n^{3}+51n^{2}+27n+5}},
\end{equation*}$$

which can be found in section 7 of [this](http://www.ift.uni.wroc.pl/~mwolf/Poorten_MI_195_0.pdf) van der Poorten's paper.

Comment: @Américo: I guess that completes the proof of convergence to $\zeta(3)$. As I said, it was derived from the CF Tito had; both the original CF and the even part converge, so they should converge to the same value.

Comment: Right! Perhaps you might add the derivation of this even part.

Comment: Bah, that was tedious to write out in full. I hope it's useful...

Comment: Thanks, J.M. Yes, it certainly was useful. I didn't realize one could derive Apery's cfrac from it!  :-)

Comment: Very good! (It is not easy).

Comment: Thanks Américo! I couldn't have made it complete without your comment...

Comment: @J.M. I just realized you're from the Philippines too. :)

Comment: @Tito, indeed I am in the Philippines. (I figured out you were also from this country many moons ago.)

Comment: @J.M.: I made some minor aesthetic changes. :)

Comment: I wonder if this can be modified to prove the two yet unproven cfracs for Apery constant found by Ramanujan machine: http://www.ramanujanmachine.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/zeta3.pdf (seems somehow similar, only last two are unproven)

Comment: @Sil Re your last comment: I think so, at least for the penultimate one. See here https://mathoverflow.net/a/425112. I think the method used in the quoted French article is pretty similar. (The team of Ramanujan machine is aware of that, but they don't update their site that often!)

Comment: @Wolfgang Yea I am aware of that article, I sent the link to it to Ramanujan team 2 years ago (twice), they haven't been able to update their website since then and they still claim it's new and unproven - I find that very unprofessional behavior. I am not sure how the method in that article relates to this answer though, but I must admit I did not study it too thoroughly (and well it was in french so...). I'll check your MO link later on, thank you.

Comment: For the record: updated van der Poorten link for the first comment: http://pracownicy.uksw.edu.pl/mwolf/Poorten_MI_195_0.pdf